# In $\triangle ABC$, we have $AB = 14$, $BC = 16$, and $\angle A = 60^\circ$. Find the sum of all possible values of $AC$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In $\triangle ABC$, we have $AB = 14$, $BC = 16$, and $\angle A = 60^\circ$. Find the sum of all possible values of $AC$.

When I use the Law of Cosines, I get a quadratic like expected. However, when I use Vieta's Formulas to get the sum of the roots, I get the wrong answer. Please help me figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: We can't say what you did wrong without seeing the work.

Comment: Note that as $BC>AB$, there can be only one possible value of $AC$ (this is the [SsA theorem](https://www.andrews.edu/~calkins/math/webtexts/geom07.htm)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did wrong was forgetting that there is a negative solution!

When you use the Law of Cosines, you get
$$\begin{align}16^2 &= 14^2 + x^2 - 2(14)(x)cos(60^\circ) \\
        16^2 - 14^2 &= x^2 - 28x\cdot(\frac{1}{2}) \\
        16^2 - 14^2 &= x^2 - 14x \\
                 60 &= x^2 - 14x \\
                  0 &= x^2 - 14x - 60. \end{align}$$
Then we realize that one of the roots is negative leaving us with the answer
$$\boxed{7 + \sqrt{109}.}$$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Using the law of cosines we have,
$$\cos A=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$$
$$\cos\frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{b^2+196-256}{28b}$$
$$\frac12=\frac{b^2+196-256}{28b}$$
$$14b=b^2-60$$
$$b=7+\sqrt{109}$$
$$b\ne7-\sqrt{109}\mbox{ because the length cannot be in negative}$$

Comment: Make sure to show the reasoning why it is only positive. Very nice diagram!

Comment: @OjaswUpadhyay I edited